# Mysql workbench: how to view logs on server from remote machine?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have running mysql server, and want to see logs on remote machin using Workbench->Server Administration->Server Logs.

But I get message like:

```
You have not enabled reroute administration for this server.
Please enable remote administration for this server instance and try again.
```

How can I enable remote administration, and what exactly it is?

Comment: I highly recommend you railscast website for tutorials, http://www.railscasts.com

Answer (score 3):

In home page of workbench, below Server Administration section, there is **Manage Server Instances**. By clicking there you can choose your server and enable remote management on that window.

Answer (score -1):

1. ssh to server
2. edit /etc/my.cnf mysql configuration file
3. Make sure line skip-networking is commented or remove line
4. add line : bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP  that your server-ip is mysql server ip
5. restart mysql